# Azure AD Apps: Migrating to v2.0

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-ad-msal

This is my scenario: Client Windows Forms app authenticates with Azure AD and uses the access token to access several web api services. Until now, I was using the endpoint 1 and using the Azure portal to register both apps. It seems like there's a new way now, but I'm a little lost here.

For starters, it seems like both apps (client and server) can be registered in the same app in the new apps portal (https://apps.dev.microsoft.com). I do see a place to add platforms and I have added entries for the native and web api. But where do I go from here? For instance, in the azure portal, I must configure the client app in order for it to call the web api services. How do I that here?

Is there a complete sample for this scenario like the one we have to ADAL (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-code-samples#native-application-to-web-api)?

Thanks,

Regards,
Luis

Comment: What is your reason to migrate? Of course one is to get dynamic consent (which doesn't exist in v1). But if you don't need that, you could continue using v1.

Comment: That's exactly what I said, but unfortunately, I'm only a simple developer :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please firstly refer to [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-v2-compare) to know what's different about the v2.0 endpoint .When you build applications that integrate with Azure Active Directory, you need to decide whether the v2.0 endpoint and authentication protocols meet your needs. Please see the [limitations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-v2-limitations) of azure ad v2.0, such as you can use the v2.0 endpoint to build a Web API that is secured with OAuth 2.0. However, that Web API can receive tokens only from an application that has the same Application ID .

The v2.0 endpoint does not support SAML or WS-Federation; it only supports Open ID Connect and OAuth 2.0 ,To better understand the scope of protocol functionality supported in the v2.0 endpoint, read through [OpenID Connect and OAuth 2.0 protocol reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-v2-protocols).

You could refer to document [how to call a web API from a .NET web app with Azure AD V2.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-v2-devquickstarts-webapp-webapi-dotnet) (using MSAL to acquire and use access tokens),  and [here](https://github.com/AzureADQuickStarts/AppModelv2-WebAPI-DotNet) is the code sample on Github . The document includes how to add basic sign-in to a web app or how to properly secure a web API in azure ad v2.0 .